# Max-width 760px for block in Bootstrap4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to set block content width to 760px (best for line-lenght) and center it horizontal on the page. Is it possible in pure Boostrap 4 without own CSS?

With the "col-8" class the block content is 730px wide.
With "col-10 px-5" classes the content of the block is 853,984px wide.

In CSS is it easy:

```
div{  
    margin:0 auto;  
    max-width:760px
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code and explain what's not working with max-width?

Comment: since Bootstrap works with %, you will need own CSS to make it exactly 760px

Answer (score 0):

The divs container should have the `d-flex justify-content-center` classes which will made it to be in center. The `max-width` means the `div`'s MAXIMUM `width` will be 760px only if the inner content is that wide. You need just `width` for that.

OR in boostrap the `row` class is `display:flex` by default, you can use that too. Just pay attention to the default margins. (margin-left/margin-right: -8px)

```
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div> // with the style="width: 760px;"
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row justify-content-center mx-0">
    <div> // with the style="width: 760px;"
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you show your code? if the div is inside a div with class container-fluid, just add col to your div class, it's take all width possible in the screen.

Comment: <div class="row">
<div class="">
{content}
</div></div>